# Error while creating DBLInk in Spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring

I have Created the DB in Spring-JDBC like this.
I am using the oracle database .

```
    public static void db_link()
   {
        String db_link="CREATE DATABASE LINK LOCAL CONNECT TO abc IDENTIFIED BY abc USING '10.203.200.19:1800/Axe'";    
        jdbcTemplateObject.update(db_link);
        System.out.println("DB_Link is created");
        return;
   }
```

and calling this method in main method as

```
StudentJDBCTemplate.db_link();
```

No i m getting the error as

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [CREATE DATABASE LINK LOCAL CONNECT TO abc IDENTIFIED BY abc USING '10.203.200.19:1800/Axe']; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:98)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:407)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:519)
at com.sample.tcs.StudentJDBCTemplate.db_link(StudentJDBCTemplate.java:21)
at com.sample.tcs.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:18)
```

please provide the some assistance.

Comment: Error clearly says you have provided insufficient credentials. Try with correct credentials.

Comment: I m giving the correct Credential but not able to create it. Anything more i have to pass??